# waiting for MSBuild Delete to complete

Tags: msbuild

I am using MSBuild and have a Delete task that deletes all the files under a directory.  The next task cleans out the directory of any folder by using RemoveDir.  I have a timing issue where the directory isn't always completely clean of files from the Delete command before the RemoveDir command runs.  Happens about half the time, and when it does the script errors out, b/c the RemoveDir can't remove directories for which files exist in them.

Can someone help me with a way to fix this problem?

Comment: RemoveDir removes all files and sub-directories recursively. You don't have to clean out the directory before calling RemoveDir. RemoveDir in your case is failing because something is using the directory or one of the files in it. Since it is a timing issue, I would suggest running msbuild with detailed logging ( option /v:d in msbuild command line) and once you hit the repro carefully examine the log file looking of other tasks that are likely to use files or directories you are trying to remove.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you are calling the `RemoveDir` task after the `Delete` action has been run by using `DependsOnTargets`:

```
<Target Name="RemoveDirectories" DependsOnTargets="DeleteFiles">
  <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToRemove)" />
</Target>
```

However it's probable that timing is not the real issue here. The issue may be that `DeleteFiles` fails to delete some locked or read-only files, which as a result fails the `RemoveDir` task to complete.
In this case consider using [MSBuild Extension Pack's Folder class](http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/4.0.4.0/html/c0f7dd21-7229-b08d-469c-9e02e66e974b.htm) which can forcefully remove all files.

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Folder TaskAction="RemoveContent" Path="@(DirsToRemove)" Force="true" />
```